# UICollectionView performBatchUpdates crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I'm using UICollectionView to display gallery images in order to customize the photo selection. Anyway, the problem happens is that when the user clicks on an image that's possibly on **iCloud** and not on device, then user clicks Done.

The app Crashes at line, `[collectionView performBatchUpdates:]` with error:

> "NSInternalInconsistencyException". I know what this error means, but can't manage to solve it.

**Code:**

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    PHFetchResultChangeDetails *collectionChanges = [changeInstance changeDetailsForFetchResult:self.fetchResult];
    if (collectionChanges) {

        self.fetchResult = [collectionChanges fetchResultAfterChanges];

        UICollectionView *collectionView = self.collectionView;
        NSArray *removedPaths;
        NSArray *insertedPaths;
        NSArray *changedPaths;

        if ([collectionChanges hasIncrementalChanges]) {
            NSIndexSet *removedIndexes = [collectionChanges removedIndexes];
            removedPaths = [self indexPathsFromIndexSet:removedIndexes withSection:0];

            NSIndexSet *insertedIndexes = [collectionChanges insertedIndexes];
            insertedPaths = [self indexPathsFromIndexSet:insertedIndexes withSection:0];

            NSIndexSet *changedIndexes = [collectionChanges changedIndexes];
            changedPaths = [self indexPathsFromIndexSet:changedIndexes withSection:0];

            BOOL shouldReload = NO;

            if (changedPaths != nil && removedPaths != nil) {
                for (NSIndexPath *changedPath in changedPaths) {
                    if ([removedPaths containsObject:changedPath]) {
                        shouldReload = YES;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (removedPaths.lastObject && ((NSIndexPath *)removedPaths.lastObject).item >= self.fetchResult.count) {
                shouldReload = YES;
            }

            if (shouldReload) {
                [collectionView reloadData];

            } else {

                [collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
                    if (changedPaths) {
                        [collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:changedPaths];

                    }

                    if (removedPaths) {
                        [collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:removedPaths];
                    }

                    if (insertedPaths) {
                        [collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:insertedPaths];
                    }

                    if ([collectionChanges hasMoves]) {
                        [collectionChanges enumerateMovesWithBlock:^(NSUInteger fromIndex, NSUInteger toIndex) {
                            NSIndexPath *fromIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:fromIndex inSection:0];
                            NSIndexPath *toIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:toIndex inSection:0];
                            [collectionView moveItemAtIndexPath:fromIndexPath toIndexPath:toIndexPath];
                        }];
                    }

                } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                }];
            }

            [self resetCachedAssets];
        } else {
            [collectionView reloadData];

        }
    }
    else {

    }
});
```